# Energy to move a charge

Tags: energy, electrostatics, capacitance

If we want to move a charge q from the positive to the negative plate of a capacitor C (with a potential V), the energy that we need is E=1/2qV or E=qV ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10):

The potential difference between the plates of the capacitor is equal to $V$. Therefore, by definition, the energy needed to move the charge $q$ from one plate to another would be equal to $qV$.

This should not be confused with the energy stored in a capacitor at a potential $V$. That is equal to $\int V dQ$ = $\int V (C dV)$ = $\dfrac{1}{2}CV^2 = \dfrac{1}{2} QV$ - where $Q(=CV)$ is the charge on the capacitor in the final state. The factor of half, appearing out of the integration, is basically an indication of the fact that the energy stored in a capacitor at potential $V$ has not been stored in it by moving the charge $Q$ through a constant potential $V$ but has been stored by moving different amounts of charges (that add up to $Q$) through different potential values ranging from $0$ to $V$.